# Given 33 natural number so that their prime divisor just with $ 7,5,2,3,11$.Prove that multiplication two number of these numbers are complete square

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Given 33 natural number so that their prime divisor just with $ 7,5,2,3,11$ is formed.
Prove that multiplication two number of these numbers are complete square.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: factor the product. It will only have even powers...

Comment: Pigeon hole principle? You must get duplicate factors since only 5 divisors?

Comment: @gt6989b: What product? I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Recall that the positive integer $n$ is a perfect square if and only if in the prime power factorization of $n$, each exponent is even.

Any number whose prime divisors do not include any primes other than the ones mentioned can be written as $k^2(2^a3^b5^c7^d11^e)$ where $a, b,c,d,e$ are $0$ or $1$. There are only $2^5$ sequences of $0$'s and/or $1$'s of length $5$. Now use the Pigeonhole Principle.

Comment: Nicolas Can you explain $k^2(2^a3^b5^c7^d11^e)$ and what is $k^2$?

Comment: Look for example at the number $2^3\cdot3^0\cdot5^7\cdot7^2\cdot11^5$. This is $(2^2\cdot5^6\cdot7^2\cdot11^4)(2^1\cdot3^0\cdot5^1\cdot7^0\cdot 11^1)$, which is $(2\cdot5^3\cdot 7\cdot 11^2)^2(2^1\cdot3^0\cdot5^17^0\cdot 11^1)$. So $k=2\cdot 5^3\cdot 7\cdot 11^2$. There may be the odd typo!

Comment: Thanks for example. case 32+1 is one of 32 case. it is true?

Comment: Because there are $33$ numbers, two of the associated strings of $0$'s and/or $1$'s will be identical. If $x$ and $y$ are numbers that give rise to identical strings of $0$'s and $1$'s, their product will only have even exponents, so will be a perfect square. Here is a ridiculously simplified example. Take $3$ powers of $5$. Then the product of two of these is a perfect square. For if $2$ or more of the exponents are even, the product of the two numbers with even exponents is a perfect square. If $2$ or more of the exponents are odd, the product of the numbers with odd exponents is a square.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  : When you explain $k^2(2^a3^b5^c7^d11^e)$ with the example it is obvious.But how did you think that the given numbers can be written in $k^2(2^a3^b5^c7^d11^e)$ this form.

Comment: Well, it is immediate that for each of our $5$ primes, the only thing that matters is the parity of the exponent.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  you need the product to have an even number of powers of each of the primes.  How many combinations of odd/even powers are possible?

Comment: Can you guide me more? I don't know how to count all possibles?

Comment: @misi10:  it is like flipping a coin.  If you had only one prime, there would be 2 possibilities:  odd or even.  If you had two primes, there would be 4:  EE, OE, EO, OO.  Can you keep going?